# No error but no ITEM is showing out

Tags: php, database

Hello this is the code in my php, i dont get error but the items in the database doesn't show and only the else tag is execute.

```
<?php

                    $sql = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM bgk9z_items');

                    if ($sql->fetchColumn() > 0) { // 

                        while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th id="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="toggle" /></th>
                                <td id="titre"><? echo $result['title']; ?>
                                    <div class="opt"><span class="up"><a href="index.php?page=update&itemid=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">Modifier</a></span> <span class="del"><a href="index.php?page=req_supp&itemid=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">Supprimer</a></span> <span class="sho"><a href="">Afficher</a></span></div>
                                </td>
                                <td id="extrait"><? $string = $result['introtext']; $long = (strlen($string) > 13) ? substr($string,0,280).'...' : $string; echo $long;?></td>
                                <td id="cat"><? include_once(dirname(__DIR__) . '/controlers/show-cat-name.php'); ?></td>
                                <td id="etat"><? $rep = $result['published']; if ($rep == 1) { echo "Oui";} else{echo "Non";} ?></td>
                                <td id="image"><? echo "Image"; ?></td>
                                <td id="ident"><? echo $result['id']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?
                        }
                    } 

                    else { ?>

                        <tr><td colspan="7" style="text-align: center;  color: rgb(192, 0, 0);  font-size: 23px;  font-weight: bold;">NO ITEM TO SHOW</td></tr>

                    <?php }

            ?
```

Comment: You've only "prepared" your query.  You never actually `execute` it.